# insert a blank line between every two lines in a file using shell, sed or awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file with many lines.  I want to insert a blank line between each two lines
for example
original file

```
xfdljflsad
fjdiaopqqq
dioapfdja;
```

I want to make it as:

```
xfdljflsad

fjdiaopqqq

dioapfdja;
```

how to achieve this?
I want to use shell script, awk or sed for this?
thanks!

Answer (score 8):

With `sed`, use

```
sed G input-file
```

If pilcrow is correct and you do not want an additional newline at the end of the file,
then do:

```
sed '$!G' input-file
```

Another alternative is to use `pr`:

```
pr -dt input-file
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path, but IIUC the OP does _not_ want an extra newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

awk '{print nl $0; nl="\n"}' file

Answer (score 1):

My approach if I want to quickly regex a file.

```
vim file.txt
%s/\n/\n\n/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic awk:

```
awk 1 ORS='\n\n' file
```

Similar thing with perl:

```
perl -nE 'say' file
```

Append `| head -n -1` if final newline is unwanted.